# Modified binary search using squaring

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, binary-search

I was trying to do a modified version of binary search  with squaring. I have completed the code and it works perfectly. Here I am using squares of 2 to find the location where the key becomes less than the arr[mid] . When this becomes true, I linearly square from the old mid (stored in lo) to the current mid to search for the key.

I know that the first part is O(logN) since I am using squares to find the mid, but I am not sure whether the entire algorithm is OlogN) or not, can someone help about this. The linear scanning is obviously not O(N) as it covers only a range between lets say 2^k to 2^k+1 on the worst case. 
How do I compute its big-O complexity.

Here's the code:

```
public int search(int key, int arr[]) {
    int lo = 0, mid = 1;
    while (mid < arr.length) {
        if (key < arr[mid]) {
            break;
        } else if (key > arr[mid]) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else if (key == arr[mid]) {
            return mid;
        }
        mid *= 2;
    }

    while (lo < arr.length && lo < mid) {
        if (key == arr[lo])
            return lo;
        lo++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Is the logic true if I use fibonacci numbers? Since there is no squaring component anymore.

Comment: Its worst case is linear time: suppose `key` is located at the position immediately before half-way.  Then after the initial loop spins log2(n) times, the final loop needs n/2-1 iterations to find `key`.  You could fix this by reverting to the "usual" binary search as soon as the comparison `if (key < arr[mid])` succeeds.

Comment: Yeah I kinda figured that its O(N) or something like that. I do not want to use binary search and I want to solve this only using squaring. What I was thinking was to reset the array to the smaller array and use the same logic again on part of an array.

Comment: BTW you're not squaring `mid`, you're doubling it -- just as in a normal binary search.